# List of JMX objects and attributes?

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to implement a nagios plugin, and doing so requires that I know specifically what object and attribute I want to monitor. The thing is, I haven't been able to find a listing anywhere of the standard system jmx objects and attributes. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need to monitor things like memory pools, heap size, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can always use [mBeanServer.queryNames(null, null);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html#queryNames%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20javax.management.QueryExp%29) for getting to all MBeans registered at a certain MBeanServer (where `mBeanServer` is the `MBeanServerConnection` which you obtained either locally or remotely).

However, before implementing your own Nagios Plugins, why not using an already exisiting one ? E.g. [jmx4perl](https://jolokia.org/client/perl.html)'s `check_jmx4perl` which comes with tools for exploring the JMX namespace (like `jmx4perl <url> list` for listing all JMX MBeans with their attributes and operations or `j4psh` a readline based JMX shell with context sensitive command line completion).

Comment: Ah ok, we had been looking at check_jmx, which is an already created one. I'll look into jmx4perl. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

You can use

```
Set mbeans = mBeanServer.queryNames(null, null);
for (Object mbean : mbeans)
{
    WriteAttributes(mBeanServer, (ObjectName)mbean);
}

private void WriteAttributes(final MBeanServer mBeanServer, final ObjectName http)
        throws InstanceNotFoundException, IntrospectionException, ReflectionException
{
    MBeanInfo info = mBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(http);
    MBeanAttributeInfo[] attrInfo = info.getAttributes();

    System.out.println("Attributes for object: " + http +":\n");
    for (MBeanAttributeInfo attr : attrInfo)
    {
        System.out.println("  " + attr.getName() + "\n");
    }
}
```

This will write all the object names and their attributes...

Answer (score 2):

From a sysadmin point of view, I fully understand the bases for the question.  The standard JMX documentation, or the objects one can encounter while trying to browse JMX object trees, can be overwhelming and confusing.

I have found this [Op5 KB article](https://kb.op5.com/display/HOWTOs/Jboss+Monitoring+with+check_jmx) quite useful in providing a decent overview of JMX objects of interest for JBoss.

Obviously, one needs to adjust to fit with the monitoring system they are actually using, but there is enough in the examples for whatever nagios-based monitoring system is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [JVM platform MBean docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/mxbeans.html)?

There are examples there on to get the MBeans and interrogate them e.g.

> The [ThreadMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) platform MBean
>   provides support for monitoring thread
>   contention and thread CPU time.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure? I was hoping there would be some sort of "here's a list of every object, and here is a sublist of its component attributes." Maybe I'm underestimating how big the standard JMX stuff is?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-frame.html seemed to help a lot actually. Is there something similar for the other MX beans? Sorry if these questions are more vague than they should be, I'm not entirely sure about the semantics of JMX.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MC4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mc4j/) or [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) - it's trivial to get going with both of 'em.

Comment: I attempted to use jconsole but it doesn't work on CLI (at least it gives a bunch of errors when you try to run it).

Comment: Its a bunch of java exceptions stating that no x-server is found. Most of the jconsole documentation points to needing to use a GUI. Can't connect to the server atm to get better explanation, I'll post the exceptions later.